# What is the step to get the payment done through NFC in Android? OR how Android applications would use NFC APIs for carrying out transactions?

Tags: android, nfc

What is the step to get the payment done through NFC in Android?

I am already Ready with "Read and Write of Tag" but what are the Steps after Read/write of tag, how the payment will be done? How will Money Transaction occur in it?

I am Talking about Payload where application specific Information is stored, how this information goes into it?

how Android applications would use NFC APIs for carrying out transactions

Answer (score 0):

the payment is currently not possible unless you are cooperating with the MNO and use the SWP connected SIM card secure storage to place there the payment application, which communicate then with use of the NFC controller and antenna (using EMV standard probably) with the POS terminal. The application in the secure storage emulates the contact-less payment secure card. Using the Nexus buit-in secure element from NXP is not possible.

BR
STeN